# Excel 2013 - Filter limit minimum number of rows returned

Tags: excel, vba

Using the `Filter` tool in Excel - is there anyway in which to place a minimum limit on the number of rows returned.

For example,  if I place a filter and the number of rows returned is less than 10 then the rows aren't shown and/ or the filter doesn't take place?

Comment: You could do something on filter to count `.visible` cells and then '.clear` if there aren't enough

Answer (score 0):

Here is something you could try:

```
    Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
If ActiveSheet.FilterMode = True Then

    Rcount = ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.Range.Columns(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Cells.Count - 1

        If Rcount < 10 Then
            ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = False
        Else
        End If

Else
End If

End Sub
```

This would only work in the sheet you are working on, but still could come in handy. There will also need to be one volatile formula such as Countif on the sheet - to trigger.

Otherwise, this works to a point quite well.

Unfortunately, however, if you choose a result with less than 10 - it disables the filter as a whole. I've tried adding the code to turn it back on, but it errors in this case - you might have some luck on that front.

I hope that this is something like you were looking for none the less